How to join the last two occurences of each ID in a list of dictionaries into one list
I have a list like this:
list1 = [
    {'id': 'ABC', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 1, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'ABC', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 2, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'ABC', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 3, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'ABC', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'BAC', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 7, 25, 18, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'BAC', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 7, 26, 18, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'BAC', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 1, 18, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'BAC', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'CAB', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 1, 6, 53, 3)},
    {'id': 'CAB', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 1, 17, 53, 3)},
    {'id': 'CAB', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 2, 11, 53, 3)},
    {'id': 'CAB', 'created_at': datetime.date(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)},
]

The list is sorted by id and created_at, so it's not needed to sort again.
If it were one id with no repeats, I knew I could do this:
output = '\n'.join([f"ID: {l['id']}, Created At: {l['created_at']}" for l in list1])

But regarding the following expected output, I don't know the how-to:
[
    {'id': 'ABC', 'start': datetime.date(2024, 8, 3, 11, 22, 3), 'end': datetime.date(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id' 'BAC', 'start': datetime.date(2024, 8, 1, 18, 22, 3), 'end': datetime.date(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id' 'CAB', 'start': datetime.date(2024, 8, 2, 11, 53, 3), 'end': datetime.date(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)},
]

I'm going to print the one before last column date of each id as start, and the last one as end.

Just a heads-up, I think you want datetime.datetime instead of datetime.date if you want to include the timestamp arguments. Otherwise you'll get a TypeError

@JRiggles yes you're right. I wrote the sample manually, and I did not copy that from the real-world example code. My real code is datetime.datetime.

You can do something like this:
list2 = {}

for i in list1:
    if i['id'] in list2:
        list2[i['id']].append(i['created_at'])
    else:
        list2.update({i['id']: [i['created_at']]})
        list2[i['id']].sort()

print([
    {'id': i, 'start': list2[i][-2], 'end': list2[i][-1]} for i in list2
])


You could try something like this:
import datetime
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [
    {'id': 'ABC', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 1, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'ABC', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 2, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'ABC', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 3, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'ABC', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'BAC', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 25, 18, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'BAC', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 26, 18, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'BAC', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 1, 18, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'BAC', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)},
    {'id': 'CAB', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 1, 6, 53, 3)},
    {'id': 'CAB', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 1, 17, 53, 3)},
    {'id': 'CAB', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 2, 11, 53, 3)},
    {'id': 'CAB', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)},
]

def transform(key, value):
    values = list(value)
    return {'id': key, 'start': values[-2]['created_at'], 'end': values[-1]['created_at']}

result = [transform(key, value) for (key, value) in groupby(list1, key=lambda x: x['id'])]
for x in result:
    print(x)
    print()

Output:
{'id': 'ABC', 'start': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 3, 11, 22, 3), 'end': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)}
{'id': 'BAC', 'start': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 1, 18, 22, 3), 'end': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)}
{'id': 'CAB', 'start': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 2, 11, 53, 3), 'end': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 5, 11, 22, 3)}


Here I group the list by the id and then, in the transform method, create the format that you requested by using the created_at of the second last's value in the list as the start date and the created_at of the last element as the end date.
